# how to create spring template project in sts-3.6.3?

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

please suggest if is there any other solution to do scaffolding of an app in STS.

In many examples/tutorials about creating web services using Spring MVC framework are using Spring MVC project template. I can't find it in my project tempaltes list. Am i missing some plugin installed?

Comment: if i have 100 tables in the database but i want only 50 table to generate controller and models means,how can do that in sts?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a new Rest service Spring app in STS 3.6.3 and beyond is to select the "Import Spring Getting Started Content". This allows you to get the guides from http://spring.io/guides directly into your workspace. If you look for "Rest Service" in the list of available guides, the wizard will download the initial and the completed version of this guide, showing you how to write a Rest service using the latest Spring versions. The completed version of the project could also be used for just creating a new Spring project and continue to do development from there.